# Variable not populating in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having a duh moment. I'm not getting this variable populated.

```
for i in ~/Ws/*.png; 
do 
  echo $i; 
  FNAME=cmd basename $i;
  echo $FNAME;
done;
```

I am getting the following output for example

```
home/Ws/BrainLearning.png
BrainLearning.png
```

But the last line is blank and I do not understand why. Basically `$FNAME` is not populated with the information I was expecting.

Comment: you imply that you don't have something that you expect, but there is no description of what you expect. What do you want to store in `FNAME` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to have `FNAME` filled with the basename of `$i` :

```
FNAME=$(basename $i)
echo "FNAME: $FNAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```bash
FNAME=cmd basename $i;
```

into

```bash
FNAME="cmd $(basename $i)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shown code has syntax errors and I suggest running your script on shellcheck.net

However what you're attempting to do can be done using this `find` command as well without any loop:

```bash
find ~/Ws -name '*.png' -execdir echo {} +
```